# Сохранение видеопотока

Tags: java

Есть задача - реализовать 2 сервиса, один отдает видеопоток, другой принимает его и записывает на диск. Вопрос в том, как осуществить соединение между серверами и осуществить сохранение? По какому протоколу должна происходить передача, как должны выглядеть контроллеры. Может вы знаете какую-нибудь ссылкочку, которая бы раскрыла эту тему.

Объясню чуть подробнее. Для обработки http запроса я использую спринговые @RestController. Насколько я понимаю, спринг сам подвязывает эти обработчики к реальным сервлетам (точнее, создает и регистрирует сервелеты в контейнере сервлетов). Например:

```
@RestController
public class UsersController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Можно ли как-то в таком же стиле писать контроллеры для обработки видео? Если честно, я сомневаюсь, что так можно. Видится вариант написания своих сервлетов и прочего.

Comment: А чем вас не устраивают существующие решения? Я про ffmpeg

Comment: Во-первых, просто интересно как это сделать. Во-вторых, помимо сохранения нужно еще кучу всего сделать.

Comment: Вы плохо представляете, что такое видео, раз так говорите

Comment: Ну естественно, если бы я шарил, то не задавал бы вопрос тут. Сказал же, нужны ссылочки и советы куда копать, как делать.
И я не понял, "раз так говорите" - это как?)

Comment: Воспринимайте видео как поток байтов.